# Registering SQLServer "Messages" in EntityFramework6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ssms

Is it possible to register messages from SQLServer? Informations that appear in "Messages" tab in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I have found out about `context.Database.Log`, but it doesn't work as expected. What appears on the SSMS:

```
(3 rows affected)

Completion time: 2020-05-15T15:12:34.3776215+02:00
```

What appears on C# end:

```
Closed connection at 15.05.2020 15:36:02 +02:00
```

It's not the exact same operation, but either way EF6 just shows closed connection, while SSMS shows affected rows and eventual errors.

Edit

Also fragment of sample code:

```cs
context.Database.Log = SQLServerLogHandler.LogDisplay.ServerLogDisplay;

context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
context.Employees.Add(record);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Message: " + SQLServerLogHandler.LogDisplay.Log + "- End of message");
```

```cs
    public static class LogDisplay
    {
        public static string Log { get; set; }

        public static void ServerLogDisplay(string log)
        {
            Log = log;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `(3 rows affected)` is just the way SSMS presents the row count of the query; this message cannot be literally captured. Assuming the "Completion time: " message is produced by T-SQL code `PRINT`ing it (I don't think SSMS has any option for that) these messages are exposed through `SqlConnection.InfoMessage`, but few ORMs surface this. I have no idea if EF does. It's certainly a best practice to not use this for any essential information, since it's so easy to miss. Completion time in particular is better measured locally (through `Stopwatch`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert what i actually want to do is capture ```PRINT``` messages, my triggers use this and i want to capture it on the app's end. Otherwise potential user won't know what happened if requested operation does nothing.

Comment: Actual errors (which "no rows affected" might well be) should be produced through `THROW`/`RAISERROR` on the T-SQL end, not printed. If that's adhered to consistently you'll get `SqlException`s that can be properly handled in code. Also note that `SaveChangesAsync` returns the number of objects written, though I don't know if that has a clear relationship with the row count. Otherwise, if you really want to capture `PRINT`s, you'll have to hook up an event handler to the `SqlConnection`s used/produced by EF. (I have no experience with EF beyond the trivial so I don't know how to do that.)

Comment: I also have no idea how to do it but at least i know what should i search for. Thanks for help.

Comment: Entity uses an EDMX ,mapping file that maps the tables in the database to the classes in c#.  When you make changes to the database tables you must refresh the mapping file so the classes and database are consistent.

Comment: @jdweng: did you mean to comment this on another question? I can't fathom how that would be relevant here, unless refreshing the model does something extremely interesting with informational messages that I'm not aware of.